# The Image of the Function: $f$:

Tags: functions

I am a bit confused how they arrived at this answer:

The image of the function $f: \mathbb N \to \mathbb R , f(n) := \frac{(-1)^n+1}{3} $

The answer they got was $\{0, \frac{2}{3}\}$

Can someone explain how to arrive at this conclusion?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n$ is even, then write $n = 2k$ and conclude that

$$f(n) = \frac{(-1)^{2k} + 1}{3} = \frac{1^k + 1}{3} = \frac{2}{3}$$

If $n$ is odd, write $n = 2k + 1$ and get

$$f(n) = \frac{(-1)^{2k + 1} + 1}{3} = \frac{-1 + 1}{3} = 0$$

Since every element of $\mathbb{N}$ is even or odd, we've exhausted the possibilities.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: The set $N$ has domain $[1, 2, 3, \dots]$.
The series can be broken up into:

$\sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{(-1)^n}{3} + \frac{1}{3}$

HINT 2: When does an alternating series converge? When its absolute value is monotone bounded.

Comment: we have not done series yet. The symbols mean nothing to me as of now. I'm pretty sure you can get the 0 by putting in $1$ for $n$, but I do not understand how to get 2/3... This was a multiple choice question btw.

Comment: I don't think the question has anything to do with alternating series - it's just asking about what the values of a function are.